# .names and .data in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka, arff

I am new to Weka.

I am trying to run some algorithms in Weka using UCI ML repository but I don't know how to use the .names and .data files in Weka.

Can anyone tell me how to convert .data and .name to arff format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at the "creating a .arff file" section in http://storm.cis.fordham.edu/~gweiss/data-mining/weka.html

If you want a simpler solution using only the .data file (.names are related to data description): just edit the .data file, insert a header (insert a first line with a different name for each attribute and all separated by a comma), save and rename it to .csv. Be careful that this solution shall not handle properly non basic data types and encounter problems with missing values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps but other way to use your data is to create an .arff like the example:
http://www.let.rug.nl/~coltekin/ml08/weather.arff

if your database are simple you can just make your own .arff if you wanna use a bigger database using .csv then transform into arff is more recommended

Comment: The link is broken.